# .net best practices for getting dynamic content into a page

Tags: asp.net, .net

I've been moving from classic ASP to ASP.NET and I'm a bit confused on the very basics.

I can get websites up and running using codebehind but I'm at sea as to what is the recommended way to get dynamic content onto the page. I've been using panels and labels and filling them dynamically but on pages that have forms then the entire contents of the labels/panels go into the postback which seems very inefficient. I could mark stuff individually as to be included or excluded but that seems very long winded. I have loads of dynamic content but the forms are all very small and don't even really need postback (contact & search forms etc).

Basically I know how to make it all work but I feel very much like I'm doing things in a fairly stupid way. Any direction or links to a some very basic information on how to set this stuff out would be much appreciated.

Comment: you may like this more http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Comment: The standard ASP.NET web app uses post back when you need to submit the form and save/manipulate data on the server. Now the first comment by @I4V points to the MVC pattern used for developing web applications. Based on your information you may need more of AJAX in your application if you do want to post chunks of data to server.